# What are these graphical display commands?

Tags: graphics, display, identify-this-computer

I have [a Pascal program with a fair amount of inline assembly code in it](https://github.com/besm6/besm6.github.io/blob/master/wiki/graf.pas) which demonstrates the capabilities of «Электроника МС 7401» — символьно-графический видеотерминал (Elektronika MS 7401 - alphanumeric-graphical videoterminal), made in the Ukraine in the 1980s. Its commands were described in the Soviet magazine "Microprocessor Tools and Systems" (Микропроцессорные средства и системы) in 5/1989, but a scan of that issue that I could find online in [a public library](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/M/%27%27Mikroprocessornye_sredstva_i_sistemy%27%27/_%27%27MPSS%27%27.html#1989) is incomplete, the article in question is missing.
I was able to guess the meaning of only a fraction of the commands. Replacing them with PostScript, I got a few pictures.

Here is one of the pictures drawn by the program:
[image: An abstract pattern]

Hoping that its commands follow a Western prototype, I'll provide a few translated code excerpts of the graphical primitives:

```
... obvious type definitions elided for brevity ...

(* Draws a line of the given type (solid/dotted/dashes, etc) to relative coordinates (PS rlineto) *)
procedure LINCUR(TYP,Х,Y:INТ);
begin
    WRIТЕ(’8’,TYP:0,' ',Х:0,' ',Y:0,BK)
end;

(* Same as above, but to absolute coordinates (lineto) *)
procedure LINE(TYP,Х,Y:INТ);
begin
    WRIТЕ(’7’,TYP:0,' ',Х:0,' ',Y:0,BK)
end;

(* Analog of PostScript moveto/rmoveto *)
procedure CURPT(ABS:ВООL;Х,Y:INТ);
begin
    if ABS then WRIТЕ(’4’) else WRIТЕ(’5’);
    WRIТЕ(' ',Х:0,' ',Y:0,BK)
end;

(* Draws a circle around the current point *)
procedure CIRCLE(TYP,R:INТ);
begin
    WRIТЕ(’>’,TYP:0,' ',R:0,BK)
end;

(* The coordinates are relative to the current point *)
procedure BOX(ХН,YН,ХВ,YВ:INТ);
begin
    WRIТЕ(’] ’,ХН:0,' ',YН:0,' ',ХВ:0,' ',YВ:0,BK)
end;
```

Further research revealed that the graphical mode was entered by <kbd>ESC</kbd>`F^`, after which the drawing commands and their arguments are sent as plain text, for example,

```
4 277 290
71 68 141
4 280 290
71 73 138
4 283 290
71 78 135
```

meaning, "move to (277,290), line style 1 to (68, 141), etc."
The lines are separated by the CR character (^M). The command `/` switches back to the text mode.

Were there known Western graphical terminals using space-separated decimal coordinates, numerical commands for movement and line drawing, and numerical line type selectors?

Comment: I don't recognise the command style, but in the 80s there were possibly quite a number of command styles. Do you have reason to believe that the protocol was based on a Western model? One thing I can say though, is that it is *not* related to a Tektronix command language.

Comment: @GregHewgill Its sibling [Elektronika MS 7105](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0)#%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B) was a clone of DEC VT240, and most if not all *Elektronika MS* series had Western prototypes.

Comment: @LeoB. a footnote in the magazine the original poster refers to reads that the command system was created by a Soviet scientific research facility (Applied Math Institute of Academy of Sciences)

Comment: Here's also a LiveJournal of a guy who was doing something very similar back in 2016: https://spamsink.livejournal.com/ (is this you by any chance? :) ) so you can try to leave him a message in a comment to the pinned post. Here's a direct link to the post describing this guys' experiment: https://spamsink.livejournal.com/657185.html

Comment: As for Western graphics terminals, I believe this manual could be a decent reference on several of the escape sequence sets used: https://docs.attachmate.com/reflection/14.0/rvtref.pdf

Comment: @DmytroL judging by rvtref.pdf,  it appears that the MS 7401 command language was very loosely based on Western prototypes.

Answer (score 3):

If you can read Russian, here is a [complete scan](https://www.1801bm1.com/files/retro/BOOK/MPSS/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%201989-05-06.djvu) of the magazine issue you're referring to:

In DjVu page numbering, the first page of interest is page 45.

I am not sure though if the article in question would give you much useful info as it does not contain any detailed command reference.